# getting type=" " while uploading csv file in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, csv, angular-material

I am uploading a csv file using lf-ng-md-file-input(angularjs) but while uploading it is not recognizing the type of csv file whereas it is recognizing the type of images and pdf files. I am not getting why this is happening. Can anyone tell me why it is not recognizing the type of csv file as 'text/csv'. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you`

This is my HTML code. I am using lf-ng-md-file-input for uploading file & a submit button which calls a method in controller.

```
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <div class="marginAll16">
                        <lf-ng-md-file-input lf-files='files' lf-mimetype='text/csv' accept='.csv'  multiple progress drag preview></lf-ng-md-file-input>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                        <md-button type="button" class="btn submitButton btn-lg" ng-click="uploadFiles()">Submit</md-button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

My Controller-
This is controller which is calling a service for posting files to the server.

```
$scope.uploadFiles = function(){

                 angular.forEach($scope.files,function(obj){

                     uploadService.uploadFiles(obj,$scope.userId,$scope.auth_token).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

                            console.log(data);
                        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

                        });
   });
            };
```

My Service -
Here in service I am creating a formdata object & appending "uploadedFile.lfFile" to it. uploadedFile.lfFile is a file object which contains all the file information but in this file object it is displaying type:"".

```
pkService.factory('uploadService',['$http',function($http)
{

    return{

        uploadFiles : function(uploadedFile, userId, authToken){

             var datafile = new FormData();
             datafile.append('file',uploadedFile.lfFile);

            return $http.post(hostname + 'users/upload_data_files.json?user_id='   + userId + '&auth_token=' + authToken,datafile, {

                 transformRequest: function(data) { return data; },
                headers: {'Content-Type': undefined,
                    enctype:'multipart/form-data'}
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

So, my question is why it is getting an empty type, where i am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your markup...

```
<lf-ng-md-file-input lf-files='files' lf-mimetype='text/csv' accept='.csv'  multiple progress drag preview></lf-ng-md-file-input>
```

Should look more like below.

```
<lf-ng-md-file-input lf-files="files" accept="text/csv"  multiple progress drag preview></lf-ng-md-file-input>
```